# Dockerfile image path contains invalid charector

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Deploying to Elastic Beanstalk fails with dockerfile that starts with

```
FROM dockerfile/java
```

Checking the logs reveals:

```
Invalid repository name (java), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed
Failed to pull Docker image dockerfile/java:latest
```

The validation regex does not include `/` though that is the image location. Building and running from the dockerfile works fine locally. Pushing the local image from that dockerfile to the docker repo and then retrieving it using dockerrun.aws.json works fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is similar to the discussion here on the forum.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=557893

Can you check if your file contains windows line endings? If so can try using dos2unix and convert your file to linux format.

I hope that will fix the issue for you.